# Using active records with sqlsrv (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

A lot of my code in PHP is structured using active records:

```
 $this->db->select('CAST(Cns.Name AS TEXT) as PName, CPn1.Chil_Id, CPns.Id');
  $this->db->join('CPns', 'CPn1.CPns_Id=CPns.Id');
```

I am wondering if this will be incompatible with Microsofts sqlsrv drivers, whose syntax is traditionally like this:

```
    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
     echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES

You can connect your Codeigniter with Active Records to your SQL Server.

Just take a look here for some details: https://bitbucket.org/alexbilbie/codeigniter-reactor-sqlsrvr/src/c2779ea3207d/system/database/drivers/sqlsrv?at=default

Comment: He seems to be using mssql drivers and not sqlsrv drivers to connect to SQL Server

Comment: Thanks Rares, will there be any changes needed to my active record syntax, or is it straight forward plug in play. By the way, I am using CI version 1.7.2 and PHP version 5.3

Comment: This worked perfectly. Seems like CI has gone out of their way in the last 2 years to support these drivers, awesome framework :)